# Como passar um locale para o validator.isMobilePhone?

Tags: validator

Como passo um `locale pt-BR` para o `validator.isMobilePhone` em meu schema do mongoose?
De acordo com a documentação devo usar um array, algo parecido com o código abaixo, mas o programa dá erro ao compilar.

```
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Por favor, forneça seu telefone.'],
    validate: [
      validator.isMobilePhone(options: ['pt-BR']),
      'Favor fornecer um telefone válido.'
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Re-escrevi o código dessa maneira:

```js
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Por favor, forneça seu telefone.'],
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        return validator.isMobilePhone(v, 'pt-BR');
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} não é um telefone válido.`
    }
  },
```